# Docker : Linking containers on different host machines

Tags: node.js, mongodb, docker, docker-swarm, orchestration

How can i connect two containers on different host machines in Docker ? I need to use data from mongodb on one host by a nodejs application on another host ? Can any one give me an example like this?

Comment: Please read [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

You could use the **abassador pattern** for container linking

http://docs.docker.com/articles/ambassador_pattern_linking/

**Flocker** is also addressing this issue, but needs more time for infrastructure setup:

https://docs.clusterhq.com/en/0.3.2/gettingstarted/

Answer (score 0):

You might want to checkout also Kontena (http://www.kontena.io). Kontena supports multicast (provided by Weave) and DNS service discovery. Because of DNS discovery you can predict before the deploy what addresses each container will get.

As Flocker, Kontena also needs some time for infrastructure setup: https://github.com/kontena/kontena/tree/master/docs#getting-started

But you will get service scaling and deploy automation as a bonus.

Answer (score 0):

You can connect container from different host by creating an [overlay](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/get-started-overlay/) network.

> Docker Engine supports multi-host networking out-of-the-box through
>   the overlay network driver.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't matter what machine the other container is on, all you need to is ensure that the port is exposed on that machine and then direct the second container on the first machine to the IP of the second machine.

Machine 1: Postgres:5432 172.25.8.10 `ifconfig`
Machine 2: Web Server:80 172.25.8.11 -> Point DB to 172.25.8.10:5432